# text position fixed vertically, but not horizontally

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

On the left side of my website I have a sliding door.
when you open my website the door is closed but it sticks a little bit out to the right so you can see that the door it there. It has a title on it "CV.CONTACT". Here you can see a picture:

[image]

Now the position of this title is absolute. when you click on the door, the door slides open en the title moves with it. but the problem it that when you scroll within the open door, the title also scrolls away. I want the title to be fixed in the middle. but of course when you close the door again, the title should move to the left again.

I found this fiddle, which is how it should kind of work, but unfortunately it does not work for me:
[http://jsfiddle.net/7pmrrtsc/4/][2]

horizontally it is important that the title can move to the right and left. but vertically it should be fixed.

This is my code:

```js
$("#left-door").click(function(){
  if ( $(this).hasClass("isOpen") ) {
    $(this).animate({
      left: '-300px'
    });
  } else {
    $(this).animate({
      left: '0'
    });
  }
  $(this).toggleClass("isOpen");
});
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,html {
    height: 100%;
}


.container {
  position: relative;

  background-color: grey;

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding: 50px;
}

.sliding-panel {
  position: fixed;
  color: white;
  width: 60px;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

#left-door {
  font-family: helvetica;
  background-color: white;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  top:0;
  left:-300px;
  width: 350px;
  overflow: auto;
}

p1{
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  text-align: right;
  position: absolute;
top: 45%;
right:-40px;
}

#left-door p2{
  color: black;
  margin-left: 40px;
  text-align: left;
  position:absolute;
top: 10px;
left: -20px;
width: 273px;
line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!-- head section -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>[your title here]</title>

  <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>
  <!-- body -->

  <div class="container">
      <div class="content">
        <!-- this is the space where the panels slide over -->
        this is my content
      </div>
      <div id="left-door" class="sliding-panel">
        <p1>CV • CONTACT</p1>
        <p2>
      Hi! My name is Sacha<br>
      Hi! My name is Sacha<br>
      Hi! My name is Sacha<br>
      Hi! My name is Sacha<br>
      Hi! My name is Sacha<br>
      Hi! My name is Sacha<br>
      Hi! My name is Sacha<br>
      Hi! My name is Sacha<br>
      Hi! My name is Sacha<br>
      Hi! My name is Sacha<br>
      Hi! My name is Sacha<br>
      Hi! My name is Sacha<br>
      Hi! My name is Sacha<br>
      Hi! My name is Sacha<br>
      Hi! My name is Sacha<br>
      Hi! My name is Sacha<br>
      Hi! My name is Sacha<br>
      Hi! My name is Sacha<br>
      Hi! My name is Sacha<br>
      Hi! My name is Sacha<br>
      Hi! My name is Sacha<br>
      Hi! My name is Sacha<br>
      Hi! My name is Sacha<br>
      Hi! My name is Sacha<br>
      Hi! My name is Sacha<br>
      
      </p2>
      </div>
  </div>

  <!-- NO HTML LAYOUT BELOW THIS POINT! -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="index.js"></script>

<!-- the body ends here -->
</body>
</html>
<!-- end of the html document, nothing to see here, move along -->
```

Comment: You should make a JSFiddle :)

Comment: What do you mean by a "sliding door"?

Comment: @SecretTimes I made one: https://jsfiddle.net/sachava/wpnh3vkf/20/

Answer (score 0):

Use `position:fixed` on the title. Should follow when you scroll.

**Useful hint**: don't use javascript to animate your elements, it doesn't support Hardware Acceleration and you almost can see the animation FPS.

To animate anything, try to use CSS animations. Just add a class to the door like `.open` and transition between CSS states, in your case just add:

```
#title p1{
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
.open #title p1{
  left:0;
}
```

It'll be a noticeable smoother transition and have a faster page load

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes to your CSS and HTML code and it worked as you expected. See the below code:

```js
$("#left-door").click(function () {
  if ($(this).hasClass("isOpen")) {
    $(this).animate({
      left: "-300px",
    });
  } else {
    $(this).animate({
      left: "0",
    });
  }
  $(this).toggleClass("isOpen");
});

$(window).scroll(function (e) {
  $("#title").css("left", $(window).scrollLeft() * -1);
});
```

```css
#left-door {
  font-family: helvetica;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: -300px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 100vh;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

#title {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50px;
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 37px;
  text-align: center;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

#title span:hover {
  color: rgb(255, 79, 251);
}

#content {
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.isOpen#left-door {
  left: 0;
}

.isOpen #title {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  writing-mode: unset;
  position: relative;
  right: unset;
}

.isOpen #content {
  margin-right: unset;
}
```

```html
<div id="left-door" class="sliding-panel">
      <div id="title">
        <span>CV • CONTACT</span>
      </div>

      <div id="content">
        ABOUT<br />
        <br />
        Hi! My name is Sacha van Alfen.<br />
        I am a Graphic Designer who recently graduated from the Royal Academy of
        Arts with a great interest in (motion) typography, print and exhibition
        design. I like to work digital as much as I like to work with print.
        Projects I work on vary from playful websites to data-scraping
        installations, type design, publications, broadsheets, a game about the
        ecological footprint of animal agricult, motion typography and more.
        <br />
        <br />
        <hr class="new1" />
        <br />
        <hr class="new1" />
        <br />
        CV
        <br />
        <br />
        EDUCATION
        <br />
        <br />
        2011 – 2016<br />
        Pre-university school, N&G / C&M<br />
        with German and art as electives,<br />
        St. Michael College, <br />Zaandam<br />
        <br />
        2016 – 2017<br />
        Pre-course <br />
        Gerrit Rietveld Academy, <br />Amsterdam<br />
        <br />
        2017 – now<br />
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I will suggest you use the flexible box instead of positioning.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but now the title turns 90 degrees. it should stay as it is. the only thing I am trying to achieve is that when the door is open en you scroll down, that the title stays where it (fixed) is and doesn't scroll too :)

Comment: Okay, now I understand what you are expecting. To achieve the same we need to fix the title part and only apply scrolling to the about part. I have updated your jsFiddle, check if it's what you wanted. [jsFIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/veb1syqh/1/)

Comment: Yes! this is what I meant, thank you so much :)

Comment: Welcome! you can upvote and mark this answer as accepted.